# Timeout publishing message in MassTransit request/response scenario

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to set up a MassTransit request/response scenario. The issue is that the message never arrives at the consumer. I get a “timeout waiting for response” error on PublishRequest. No other errors are showing up in the log file. Messages are being created in msmq.

Exception information:

> Exception type: TargetInvocationException 
>       Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>
> Timeout waiting for response, RequestId:
>   08cfa243-4a88-ba3a-20cf-307f54910000    at
>   MassTransit.RequestResponse.RequestImpl`1.Wait() in
>   d:\BuildAgent-03\work\8d1373c869590c5b\src\MassTransit\RequestResponse\RequestImpl.cs:line
>   124    at
>   MassTransit.RequestResponseExtensions.PublishRequest[TRequest](IServiceBus
>   bus, TRequest message, Action`1 configureCallback) in
>   d:\BuildAgent-03\work\8d1373c869590c5b\src\MassTransit\RequestResponseExtensions.cs:line
>   31    at Producer.Website.Controllers.AccountController..ctor() in
>   c:\Users\rick\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\ConsumerTest1\Producer.Website\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line
>   56

Producer setup:

```
            _bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
            {
                sbc.UseMsmq();
                sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();

                sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
                sbc.SetNetwork("Test");

               sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/consumer_test_1");

            });
```

Producer send message:

```
                var message = new AccountNewMessage()
                {
                    CorrelationId = CombGuid.Generate(),
                    UserName = “blah blah”,
                    Password = “yada yada”
                };

                this._bus.PublishRequest(message, r =>
                    {
                        r.SetTimeout(30.Seconds());

                        r.Handle<AccountNewMessageResponse>(m =>
                            {
                                var response = m;
                            });
                    });
```

Consumer setup:

```
        this.bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
            {
                sbc.UseMsmq();
                sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();

                sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
                sbc.SetNetwork("Test");

                sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/consumer_test_2");

                sbc.Subscribe(subs => subs.Instance(new AccountNewMessageConsumer()));
            });
```

Consumer:

```
public class AccountNewMessageConsumer : Consumes<AccountNewMessage>.Context
{
    public void Consume(IConsumeContext<AccountNewMessage> context)
    {
        context.Respond(new AccountNewMessageResponse()
        {
            CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId,
            ErrorCode = "1",
            UserId = new Random().Next(1, 10000).ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

Messages:

```
[Serializable]
public class AccountNewMessage : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class AccountNewMessageResponse : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What version of MT are you running?

Comment: Also, on the log file, I don't see any messages showing up. Only my own. I'll post another question on that.

Comment: We are using 2.7.2 (with RabbitMQ) and request/response is working for us. We do not use CorrelationId as MassTransit generates a request id internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to tell MassTransit how to store it's subscription info (for MSMQ).

There are two choices: `MSMQ Multicast`, which keeps subscription information in memory, and `MSMQ Runtime Services` which stores the subscription information in a database, so it persists between sessions.

Your choice of which to use will depend on whether you require permanent or temporary subscriptions - from [the docs](https://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview/subscriptions.html#permanent-v-s-temporary-subscriptions):

> Permanent subscriptions represent a subscription that you want to have
>   stay around even if your process is shut down (maybe you are doing an
>   upgrade and don’t want to miss a message). A temporary subscription is
>   to be used in the case where you won’t care if you miss a message
>   while shut down.

There's no reason you couldn't use Multicast during development / PoC and switch to RuntimeServices later. The docs page also shows how to set up each in configuration, of course with RuntimeServices you also have to set up a database.

(Note that Multicast can take a little while to set itself up, so you might need to give your test system a pause to warm up before you start pumping messages through it.)

Edit: I've appended a couple of routines which validate the subscriptions and consumers: you would call the first while setting up subscriptions (ie during sbc.Subscribe) and the second once the bus is configured. Perhaps they will help find the problem?

```
private void ValidateSubscriptions(Configurator configurator)
{
    var errors = configurator.Validate();

    Console.WriteLine("Subscription Validation");
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");

    foreach (var err in errors.Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value) == false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} Message: {1} Key: {2} Value: {3}",
            err.Disposition, err.Message, err.Key, err.Value);
    }
}

private static void ValidateBus(Configurator bus)
{
    var errors = bus.Validate();

    Console.WriteLine("Consumer Validation");
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");

    foreach (var err in errors.Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value) == false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} Message: {1} Key: {2} Value: {3}",
            err.Disposition, err.Message, err.Key, err.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried using both UseMulticastSubscriptionClient() and SetNetwork("test") in both the producer and the consumer with no change in behavior; it still times out on PublishRequest(). I updated my question with the details of the exception and the calls to set up the subscription store.

Comment: Both of those functions are identical... Neither one is showing any errors.